# Zend's Gdata/Youtube API Library's getEditLink() always null

Tags: php, zend-framework, youtube-api

When I use getEditLink() on a video entry, it is always null, even when the connected user is the video's author.

```
// $this->yt_user is the Zend_Gdata_YouTube object that is connected
//    to the API using the user's session token. This same object was
//    used to upload the video to the user's account.
// $input['get'] is sanitized $_GET. The id value is the video's ID
//    sent by Youtube after a video upload from the browser.

$videoEntry = $this->yt_user->getVideoEntry($input['get']['id']);

var_export($videoEntry->getEditLink());
```

I can verify that $videoEntry is a valid video by calling var_export($videoEntry) on it.

I need to be able to edit the video after the upload, but because getEditLink() is always null, I can't call $videoEntry->getEditLink()->getHref();

Comment: You could check out this thread - it seems pretty relevant: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/fMPw0fPXOaQ

Comment: Also: http://my-sliit.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-get-editable-video-entry-youtube.html

Comment: Ah. The examples I read never showed any arguments for the method other than the video id. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer thanks to the comments to the question.

getVideoEntry() requires the 3rd argument to be true to return an editable video entry.

```
$videoEntry = $this->yt_user->getVideoEntry($input['get']['id'], null, true);
```

None of the examples I read showed this (mainly from Google's docs or Zend's docs). They only showed the first argument.